# How do i make a link when clicked show a larger image on the page

Tags: html, css, image, gallery

Basically i want my see more button, when clicked to enlarge the image above it. So that the image appears in the middle of the page enlarged does anyone know of a way to do this, or a tutorial i could follow, would be much appreciated. by the way im fairly new to web design so a little help thanks!

Also the objects i want to change are under portfolio item

here is a link to the website:

http://www.mmicgt.com/michael_g/portfolio.html

HTML:

```
<html>

<head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>{Michael Grace} Portfolio website - {Gracey design}</title>

    <link href="css/gallery.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>

<body>

    <div id="container">      


        <ul id="navigation">

        <li><a href="index.html"><img src="images/images/home_button2.gif" onmouseover="this.src='images/images/home_button1.gif'" onmouseout="this.src='images/images/home_button2.gif'"/></a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="about.html"><img src="images/images/about_button1.gif" onmouseover="this.src='images/images/about_button2.gif'" onmouseout="this.src='images/images/about_button1.gif'"/></a>
        </li>

            <li>
                <div id="logo" style="padding:16px">
                    <img src="images/images/logo.png" />
                </div>
            </li>    

        <li><a href="portfolio.html"><img src="images/images/gallery_button1.gif" onmouseover="this.src='images/images/gallery_button2.gif'" onmouseout="this.src='images/images/gallery_button1.gif'"/></a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="contact.html"><img src="images/images/contact_button1.gif" onmouseover="this.src='images/images/contact_button2.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/images/contact_button1.gif'"/></a>
        </li>

        </ul>

      <div id="header">

          <h1><img src="images/images/gallery_03.png" /></h1>
          <h2>Portfolio.</h2>

      </div>

      <div id="line">
      </div>

      <div id="content">

        <p>Did I mention I design stuff? I've had plenty of fun creating a bunch of designs for both Univeristy and for myself as personal projects. Here's a collection of some of my favs.  
        </p>

            <div class="portfolio-item">
            <a href="#"><img src="images/home/image1.gif" alt="View more info" /></a>
            <p class="btn"><a href="#">SEE MORE</a></p>
            </div>

            <div class="portfolio-item">
            <a href="#"><img src="images/home/image2.gif" alt="View more info" /></a>
            <p class="btn"><a href="#">SEE MORE</a></p>
            </div>

            <div class="portfolio-item">
            <a href="#"><img src="images/home/image3.gif" alt="View more info" /></a>
            <p class="btn"><a href="#">SEE MORE</a></p>
            </div>

            <div class="portfolio-item">
            <a href="#"><img src="images/home/image4.gif" alt="View more info" /></a>
            <p class="btn"><a href="#">SEE MORE</a></p>
            </div>

            <div class="portfolio-item">
            <a href="#"><img src="images/home/image5.png" alt="View more info" /></a>
            <p class="btn"><a href="#">SEE MORE</a></p>
            </div>

            <div class="portfolio-item">
            <a href="#"><img src="images/home/image6.png" alt="View more info" /></a>
            <p class="btn"><a href="#">SEE MORE</a></p>
            </div>

            <div class="portfolio-item">
            <a href="#"><img src="images/home/image7.png" alt="View more info" /></a>
            <p class="btn"><a href="#">SEE MORE</a></p>
            </div>

            <div class="portfolio-item">
            <a href="#"><img src="images/home/image8.gif" alt="View more info" /></a>
            <p class="btn"><a href="#">SEE MORE</a></p>
            </div>

        </div>  

      </div>

    </div>

</body>
```

css:

```
body {
background: url(../images/images/bg_page.gif) center center;
font: 16px Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif; 
color: #636363; 
line-height: 24px;
}

#container {
width: 940px;
margin: 0 auto;
margin-top: 100px;
}

    #header {
    height: 177px;
    background: url(../images/home/header.gif) top center;
    padding: 52px 0 0 28px;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;

    }

            #header h1 {
            margin: 0px 0 20px 0; 
            }

            #header h2 {
            width: 510px; 
            font: 30px Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif; 
            color: #f2f0eb; 
            letter-spacing: 2px; 
            margin: 0 0 20px 0;
            text-shadow: 0px 3px 3px #494949;
            }

    #logo {
    width: 272px;
    height: 214px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 49.5%;
    top: 11%; 
    margin-left: -150px;
    margin-top: -86px;
    z-index: 2;
    }

    #navigation {
    position: relative;
    height: 60px;
    }

        #navigation li {
        display: inline;
        width: 160px; 
        height: 60px; 
        float: left; 
        padding: 13px 0 0 16px;
        }

            #navigation li:nth-child(1) {
            margin: 0 0 0 -57px;
            }
            #navigation li:nth-child(2) {
            margin: 0 0 0 0;
            }
            #navigation li:nth-child(3) {
            margin: 0 0 0 0;
            }
            #navigation li:nth-child(4) {
            margin: 0 0 0 77px;
            }


    #content {
    height: 592px;
    background: url(../images/home/bg_body.png) top center;
    padding: 41px 69px 50px 28px; 
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
    }

        #content h2 {
        font: 30px Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif; 
        letter-spacing: 2px; 
        margin: 0 0 20px 0;
        }

        #content h3 {
        font: 26px Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif; 
        letter-spacing: 2px; 
        margin: 0 0 20px 0;
        }

        #content p {
        margin: 0 0 30px 0;
        }

        #content a {
        color: #671111; 
        text-decoration: none;
        }
                #content a:hover {
                color: #a12121;
                }

                #content .portfolio-item {
                width: 190px; 
                padding: 1px; 
                background: #eee; 
                text-align: center; 
                float: left;
                margin: 0 7px 14px 7px;
                }

                #content .portfolio-item p.btn {
                margin: 0;
                }

                #content .portfolio-item p.btn a {
                display: block; 
                width: 183px; 
                height: 29px; 
                padding: 7px 0 0 0;
                background: url(images/images/background-seemore_03.gif);
                font-weight: bold; 
                text-align: center; 
                text-transform: uppercase;
                text-decoration: none;
                }

    #line {
    height: 4px;
    background: url(../images/home/line.gif) top center;
    position: relative;
    }
```

Comment: Hi, you should take a look on the lightbox plugin for jQuery, it will fit your need I guess and there are a lot of tutorial on using it. http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/

Comment: ok it works but how would i make it join with the see more link
into this
<p class="btn"><a href="#">SEE MORE</a></p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look for satisfying js lib for that. They are often easy-to-install and do not require any coding for basic usage. Here're some popular examples:

- [LightBox](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/) - Very popular lib
- [FancyBox](http://fancybox.net/) - I used it for most of my projects, it's lightweight and really fancy

Theese libs support HTML content to show up, so you can add any content to youy pictures. They are recommended, because they are developed for a long time and stable enough. Good luck!

**EDIT:**

```
<!-- Usage example -->
<a href="big_image.jpg" rel="lightbox">See more</a>
```

Link can have any inline content - image, text, etc.

Comment: yep i tried light box works great just not sure how would i link it to the see more button

Comment: into this
<p class="btn"><a href="#">SEE MORE</a></p>

Comment: Great! Just added an example usage